# c++ - reading and writing a large bmp file

Tags: c++, arrays, image, bmp

I have to create a program in c++ (standard libraries only) that detects edges with Sobel operator on a bmp photo and writes the result to the output bmp file (no need to create it, just to write into a previously created file). To do so I have to read an input bmp file and put it into a dynamic 2x2 array. Reading must be done in two different modes (picked up by an user) - first one is to read whole image into a memory in a dynamic array, second one is to read an image piece by piece (pieces with set size). I have no idea how to do a second mode, i guess it has to somehow read an exact number of lines from an input file, use a sobel on them and put them together in an output file, but i have no idea how to implement it. can you tell me how to start it?

this is some code that i've made, it's incomplete since i have to do a second mode but the first one is done (the Sobel operator code was taken from Dwayne Phillips' book about processing images in C, so it's more C-like)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
typedef unsigned char byte_t;  //krotszy zapis

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// BMP STRUCTS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

struct BITMAPFILEHEADER {
    byte_t bfType[2];      
    byte_t bfSize[4];      
    byte_t bfReserved1[2]; 
    byte_t bfReserved2[2];  
    byte_t bfOffBits[4];   
};

struct BITMAPINFOHEADER  {
    byte_t biSize[4];         
    byte_t biWidth[4];          
    byte_t biHeight[4];         
    byte_t biPlanes[2];        
    byte_t biBitCount[2];       
    byte_t biCompression[4];    
    byte_t biSizeImage[4];     
    byte_t biXpelsPerMeter[4]; 
    byte_t biYpelsPerMeter[4]; 
    byte_t biCrlUses[4];
    byte_t biCrlImportant[4];
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////// SOBEL MASKS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

short mask_0[3][3] = {    //S1
{ 1, 2, 1},
{ 0, 0, 0},
{-1, -2, -1} };

short mask_1[3][3] = {    //S2
{ 2, 1, 0},
{ 1, 0, -1},
{ 0, -1, -2} };

short mask_2[3][3] = {    //S3
{ 1, 0, -1},
{ 2, 0, -2},
{ 1, 0, -1} };

short mask_3[3][3] = {    //S4
{ 0, -1, -2},
{ 1, 0, -1},
{ 2, 1, 0} };

short mask_4[3][3] = {    //S5 (-S1)
{-1, -2, -1},
{ 0, 0, 0},
{ 1, 2, 1} };

short mask_5[3][3] = {    //S6 (-S2)
{-2, -1, 0},
{-1, 0, 1},
{ 0, 1, 2} };

short mask_6[3][3] = {    //S7 (-S3)
{-1, 0, 1},
{-2, 0, 2},
{-1, 0, 1} };

short mask_7[3][3] = {    //S8 (-S4)
{ 0, 1, 2},
{-1, 0, 1},
{-2, -1, 0} };



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// BASIC FUNCTIONS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int wordValue(byte_t* t)    //value of 2 byte long variable
{
    return t[0] + t[1] * 256;
}

int dwordValue(byte_t* t)   //value of 4 byte long variable
{
    return t[0] + t[1] * 256 + t[2] * 256 * 256 + t[3] * 256 * 256 * 256;
}

int menudisplay()
{
    cout << "<------------------------------------- OPERATOR SOBELA - PROJEKT -------------------------------- >" << endl;
    cout << "<                                    Welcome at Sobel!                            >" << endl;
    cout << "<           Sobel detects edges in BMP files.               >" << endl;
    cout << "<                                    It has two modes:                              >" << endl;
    cout << "<                          1. Reading whole image into a RAM                             >" << endl;
    cout << "<                          2. Reading an image piece by piece (for big files)                               >" << endl;
    cout << "<                      To pick a mode, just enter 1 or 2.                        >" << endl;
    cout << "<           Then enter a name of an input file with .bmp.    >" << endl;
    cout << "< Later enter a name of an output value with .bmp. >" << endl;
    cout << "<                                            Have fun!                                     >" << endl;
    cout << "<-----------------------  ----------------------->" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Your choice: ";
}

void menuservice()
{
    menudisplay();

powrot:
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        save_to_bmp();
        break;
    case 2:
        /*pieces of image*/
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Bad choice! Pick a mode once again: ";
        goto powrot;
        break;
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// BMP READING //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void readBFH(ifstream& ifs, BITMAPFILEHEADER& bfh) //reading bfh
{
    ifs.read((char*)&(bfh.bfType), sizeof(bfh.bfType));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bfh.bfSize), sizeof(bfh.bfSize));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bfh.bfReserved1), sizeof(bfh.bfReserved1));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bfh.bfReserved2), sizeof(bfh.bfReserved2));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bfh.bfOffBits), sizeof(bfh.bfOffBits));
}

void readBIH(ifstream& ifs, BITMAPINFOHEADER& bih) //reading bih
{
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biSize), sizeof(bih.biSize));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biWidth), sizeof(bih.biWidth));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biHeight), sizeof(bih.biHeight));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biPlanes), sizeof(bih.biPlanes));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biBitCount), sizeof(bih.biBitCount));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biCompression), sizeof(bih.biCompression));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biSizeImage), sizeof(bih.biSizeImage));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biXpelsPerMeter), sizeof(bih.biXpelsPerMeter));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biYpelsPerMeter), sizeof(bih.biYpelsPerMeter));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biCrlUses), sizeof(bih.biCrlUses));
    ifs.read((char*)&(bih.biCrlImportant), sizeof(bih.biCrlImportant));
}

void writeBFH(ofstream& ofs, BITMAPFILEHEADER& bfh) //zapisywanie naglowka pliku
{
    ofs.write((char*)&(bfh.bfType), sizeof(bfh.bfType));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bfh.bfSize), sizeof(bfh.bfSize));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bfh.bfReserved1), sizeof(bfh.bfReserved1));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bfh.bfReserved2), sizeof(bfh.bfReserved2));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bfh.bfOffBits), sizeof(bfh.bfOffBits));
}

void writeBIH(ofstream& ofs, BITMAPINFOHEADER& bih) //writing bih
{
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biSize), sizeof(bih.biSize));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biWidth), sizeof(bih.biWidth));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biHeight), sizeof(bih.biHeight));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biPlanes), sizeof(bih.biPlanes));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biBitCount), sizeof(bih.biBitCount));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biCompression), sizeof(bih.biCompression));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biSizeImage), sizeof(bih.biSizeImage));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biXpelsPerMeter), sizeof(bih.biXpelsPerMeter));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biYpelsPerMeter), sizeof(bih.biYpelsPerMeter));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biCrlUses), sizeof(bih.biCrlUses));
    ofs.write((char*)&(bih.biCrlImportant), sizeof(bih.biCrlImportant));
}

void displaydata(BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh, BITMAPINFOHEADER bih)    //displaying data
{
    cout << "Input file data:" << endl;
    cout << "<---------------------------------------->";
    cout << "File length: " << dwordValue(bfh.bfSize) << endl;
    cout << "Header size: " << dwordValue(bih.biSize) << endl;
    cout << "Image width: " << dwordValue(bih.biWidth) << endl;
    cout << "Image height: " << dwordValue(bih.biHeight) << endl;
    cout << "Image size: " << dwordValue(bih.biSizeImage) << endl;
    cout << "Real amount of picture's bytes: " << dwordValue(bih.biSizeImage) - dwordValue(bfh.bfOffBits) << endl;
    cout << "Zeros per row: " << zerosPerRow(bfh, bih) << endl;
}

int zerosPerRow(BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh, BITMAPINFOHEADER bih)
{
    int realsize = dwordValue(bih.biSizeImage) - dwordValue(bfh.bfOffBits);
    int height = dwordValue(bih.biHeight);
    int width = dwordValue(bih.biWidth);
    int zeros = 0;
    if (width % 4 != 0)
    {
        int bytesPerRow = width * 3;   
        zeros = (bytesPerRow / 4 + 1) * 4 - bytesPerRow;
    }
    return zeros;
}

void save_to_bmp()
{   
    char infile[100];
    char outfile[100];
    cout << "Enter input file: ";
    cin >> infile;
    cout << "Enter output file: ";
    cin >> outfile;

    ifstream ifs(infile, ios::binary);      //input stream
    ofstream ofs(outfile, ios::binary);     //output stream
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;                  
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;                   

    if (!ifs.is_open() || !ofs.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Opening error!";
        save_to_bmp();
    }
    else {
        readBFH(ifs, bfh);
        readBIH(ifs, bih);
        writeBFH(ofs, bfh);
        writeBIH(ofs, bih);

        displaydata(bfh, bih);

        /*reading values of pixels*/
        unsigned char p;        //value of a single pixel
        short** the_image;      //input image array
        the_image = new short* [dwordValue(bih.biWidth)];
        for (int i = 0; i < dwordValue(bih.biWidth); i++)
        {
            the_image[i] = new short [dwordValue(bih.biHeight)];
        }

        short** out_image;      //output image array
        out_image = new short* [dwordValue(bih.biWidth)];
        for (int i = 0; i < dwordValue(bih.biWidth); i++)
        {
            out_image[i] = new short[dwordValue(bih.biHeight)];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dwordValue(bih.biHeight); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dwordValue(bih.biWidth); j++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
                {
                    ifs.read((char*)&p, sizeof(char));
                    ofs.write((char*)&p, sizeof(char));
                }
                the_image[i][j] = (short)p;
                out_image[i][j] = (short)p;
            }
        }
        /*zera*/
        for (int i = 0; i < zerosPerRow(bfh, bih); i++)
        {
            ifs.read((char*)&p, sizeof(char));
            ofs.write((char*)&p, sizeof(char));
        }

        sobel(the_image, out_image, dwordValue(bih.biWidth), dwordValue(bih.biHeight), dwordValue(bih.biBitCount));


        for (int i = 0; i < dwordValue(bih.biWidth); i++)
        {
            delete[] the_image[i];
            the_image[i] = NULL;
        }
        delete[] the_image;
        the_image = NULL;
        ifs.close();
        ofs.close();

        char a;
        cout << "File has been read. Enter anything to exit program";
        cin >> a;
        system("cls");
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////// SOBEL CODE //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


short** image, ** out_image;
long  rows, cols, bits_per_pixel;

int perform_convolution(short** image, short** out_image, long rows, long cols, long bits_per_pixel)
{
    char response[80];
    int a, b, i, is_present, j, sum;

    short max, min, new_hi, new_low;

    new_hi = 250;
    new_low = 16;
    if (bits_per_pixel == 4) {
        new_hi = 10;
        new_low = 3;
    }

    min = 0;
    max = 255;
    if (bits_per_pixel == 4)
        max = 16;

    /*cleaning an output array*/
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            out_image[i][j] = 0;


    printf("\n ");

    for (i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++) {
        if ((i % 10) == 0) { printf("%4d", i); }
        for (j = 1; j < cols - 1; j++) {


            /*convolution*/

            /*kierunek 0*/

            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] *
                        mask_0[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;


            /*kierunek 1*/

            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] * mask_1[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;


            /*kierunek 2*/

            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] * mask_2[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;

            /*kierunek 3*/

            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] * mask_3[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;

            /*kierunek 4*/

            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] * mask_4[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;

            /*kierunek 5*/

            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] * mask_5[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;


            /*kierunek 6*/
            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] * mask_6[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;

            /*kierunek 7*/

            sum = 0;
            for (a = -1; a < 2; a++) {
                for (b = -1; b < 2; b++) {
                    sum = sum + image[i + a][j + b] * mask_7[a + 1][b + 1];
                }
            }
            if (sum > max) sum = max;
            if (sum < 0)   sum = 0;
            if (sum > out_image[i][j])
                out_image[i][j] = sum;


        }
    }

    return(1);
}

int fix_edges(short** im, int w, long rows, long cols)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = w; i > 0; i--) {
        im[i - 1][i - 1] = im[i][i];
        im[i - 1][cols - (i - 1)] = im[i][cols - 1 - (i - 1)];
        im[rows - (i - 1)][i - 1] = im[rows - 1 - (i - 1)][i];
        im[rows - (i - 1)][cols - (i - 1)] = im[rows - 1 - (i - 1)][cols - 1 - (i - 1)];
    } 

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = w; j > 0; j--) {
            im[i][j - 1] = im[i][j];
            im[i][cols - j] = im[i][cols - j - 1];
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        for (i = w; i > 0; i--) {
            im[i - 1][j] = im[i][j];
            im[rows - i][j] = im[rows - i - 1][j];
        }
    }
    return(1);
}

int sobel(short** the_image, short** out_image, long rows, long cols, long bits_per_pixel)     //wykrywanie krawedzi operatorem sobela
{
    perform_convolution(the_image, out_image, rows, cols, bits_per_pixel);
    fix_edges(out_image, 1, rows, cols);
    return(1);
}

int main()
{
    menuservice();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note if you are only concerned with the second part, leave the code only used by the first part out of the question.  If it's not relevant, it's noise standing between you and a good quality answer.

Comment: yes, but I can't leave it